# How to apply dot-based JSONPath to Play JsValue

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I have a String variable that represents some dot-based JsPath (like `store.book[0].title`) and I have a play.api.libs.json.JsValue object.
I want to apply the path as a variable to the object and get Option[JsValue].
Are there any libraries that could do it? If not, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dijon](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon) for that.

Add dependencies:

```
libraryDependency += "com.github.pathikrit" %% "dijon" % "0.3.0"
```

Add imports:

```
import scala.language.dynamics._
import com.github.pathikrit.dijon._
```

Parse your JSON from a string and query it:

```
val json = parse(
  """{
     "store": {
       "book": [
         {
            "title": "Functional Programming in Scala"
         }
       ]
     }
   }""")

assert(json.store.book(0).title == "Functional Programming in Scala")
assert(json.store.book(0).price == None)

def findInJson(json: SomeJson)(selector: SomeJson => SomeJson): SomeJson =
  selector(json)

assert(findInJson(json)(_.store.book(0).title) == "Functional Programming in Scala")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not sure though that it can do what I am looking for... I need to traverse the json object having path as a variable. Something like ```def findJsValue(path: String): Option[JsValue]``` whereas the suggested library does not seem to offer it out of the box

Comment: If `findInJson` is not suitable for you then you can try `JsonPath.query` from the https://github.com/gatling/jsonpath. It accepts a string representation of the selector that will be parsed and compiled before applying for the parsed JSON.

Comment: It seems to be more what I am looking for. However, they say that the library is for for internal usage... Dunno if I dare to rely on it in a project... :( Thank you anyway for your input. I appreciate it

Comment: Could you please give more context about your challenge? Why you don't know upfront for what you will look for after parsing of JSON? Will some standardized query languages for JSON like http://jmespath.org help for your case?

Comment: jmespath looks like what I am looking for! Need to play with it, but it sounds very good :) If you form it in an answer, I can mark it as accepted ;) Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm happy that it helps. Also, it should easy to implement JMESPath integration with any JSON AST, [like here](https://github.com/burtcorp/jmespath-java/blob/master/jmespath-jackson/src/main/java/io/burt/jmespath/jackson/JacksonRuntime.java).

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try :)

Comment: You are welcome! Probably, yet another approach of using [JSTL](https://github.com/schibsted/jslt) (a transformation language for JSON) will be suitable for you too. More about their reasons you can see in [this talk](https://vimeo.com/289470470)

Comment: This also looks interesting. Thank you!